# Ubuntu doesn't recognize external monitors connected via HDMI

Tags: hdmi, external-monitor

My laptop is an ASUS-x556ur, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and the x.org display driver (I tried switching to Nvidia and restarting and reconnecting, didn't work...)

I usually connect my laptop to 2 external monitors - one is a desktop screen and the other my room TV. In the morning both of them were working fine.

I went to college and used my laptop there and also updated all the packages.
When I came back I tried to connect it to both screens - none of them are even recognised anymore.

I tried updating again, removing the latest installed packages and restarting and trying different settings and combinations countless times, nothing worked.
I tried connecting a screen via VGA and it works.
My leptop was fine, nothing happened to the HDMI port at any point of the day.
I dont know what to try anymore.